# hyper links and remote images in QLabel

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to display some html code in a QLabel. While the QLabel renders the html properly, the hyper link is actually not working and the image links just produce a missing icon picture rather than showing the image itself.
I am guessing that this is a limitation of QLabel and I may need to resort to QWebView, but just wanted to check if I'm missing something?!

Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])

label = QLabel()
label.setText('''<p><a href="http://www.google.com">"Go to Google"</a></p>
<p><img src="http://www.google.co.nz/logos/2012/field_hockey-2012-hp.jpg"/></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 17px;"><br /></span></p>''')

label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QLabel is not a web browser, although it can display rich text using a subset of HTML markup. [See the documentation.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)

If you want something to happen when the link is clicked, you need to use the [linkActivated()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#linkActivated) signal. Or you can use the [openExternalLink](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop) property.